# Searching/Filtering on af:Tree

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created an ADF tree using the POJO and want to perform a search on the rendered tree.
the search should traverse the rendered tree and should display only the matching nodes/leaves from the tree.

Jdev version :11.1.1.6

Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible out of the box, because of the way trees are constructed. How would you show the leaves if the nodes are filtered away?

Comment: Is there a way that I can highlight the leaf/node which matches the text entered by the user in input.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Please create a new question for this. I will answer it...

Comment: Hi Fortega, I have created a new thread for this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731116/searching-on-aftree"