# Searching on af:Tree

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created an ADF tree using the POJO and want to perform a search on the rendered tree. the search should traverse the rendered tree and should display only the matching nodes/leaves from the tree.
Is there a way that I can highlight the leaf/node which matches the text entered by the user in input.
Jdev version :11.1.1.7.1

Thanks.

Comment: Should probably provide some code that you tried to get answers..

Comment: I have tried a Method that parses an ADF bound ADF Faces tree component to find search string matches in one of the specified attribute names.Attribute names are ignored if they don't exist in the search node.The method performs a recursiv search and returns a RowKeySet with the row keys of all nodes that contain the search string,The issue now is this works fine till the time i don't perforn any action on the node which are command links in my case.After i perform click action on the command link ,the search stops working.